# no test task in gradle build

Tags: android, gradle

I am trying to build and imported Android project in Android Studio/Eclipse. 
My goal is to write automated test to the current project. First, I am trying to build the project and then to make an apk file of it so I will be able to execute real device/emulator tests on it. 
[Here are my available Gradle tasks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxBik.png) 
There is no build or test or assemble and etc. tasks which are I am looking to use so I will reach my goal.
[Here is my project tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuZj4.png)  and both build.gradle files
`

```
 apply plugin: "java"
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.13
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

### and

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
version = "1.2"
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    }
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "sdk.mobfox.com.appcore"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        archivesBaseName = "MobFox-Android-SDK-Client-" + version + ".apk"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize = "4g"
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.danikula:videocache:2.7.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'}
```

I tried to open the project in Android Studio but got the same state. 
I opened a new Gradle project in Eclipse and saw that the tasks I am looking for are available there - I believe because of the 'java-library' plugin which added to the build.gradle root file but I use the same plugin in my root build file and did not receive what I expected. 
I was succeeded to execute the Gradle "tasks" which gave me the next response in console :

> Working Directory: C:\Users\orit\Desktop\mobFox\MobFox-Android-SDK-master\MobFox-Android-SDK-master
>   Gradle User Home: C:\Users\orit.gradle
>   Gradle Distribution: Specific Gradle version 4.1
>   Gradle Version: 4.1
>   Java Home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91
>   JVM Arguments: None
>   Program Arguments: None
>   Gradle Tasks: tasks
>
> ### :tasks

### All tasks runnable from root project

### Build tasks

assemble - Assembles the outputs of this project.
build - Assembles and tests this project.
buildDependents - Assembles and tests this project and all projects that depend on it.
buildNeeded - Assembles and tests this project and all projects it depends on.
classes - Assembles main classes.
clean - Deletes the build directory.
jar - Assembles a jar archive containing the main classes.
testClasses - Assembles test classes.

### Build Setup tasks

init - Initializes a new Gradle build.
wrapper - Generates Gradle wrapper files.

### Documentation tasks

javadoc - Generates Javadoc API documentation for the main source code.

### Help tasks

buildEnvironment - Displays all buildscript dependencies declared in root project 'MobFox-Android-SDK-master'.
components - Displays the components produced by root project 'MobFox-Android-SDK-master'. [incubating]
dependencies - Displays all dependencies declared in root project 'MobFox-Android-SDK-master'.
dependencyInsight - Displays the insight into a specific dependency in root project 'MobFox-Android-SDK-master'.
dependentComponents - Displays the dependent components of components in root project 'MobFox-Android-SDK-master'. [incubating]
help - Displays a help message.
model - Displays the configuration model of root project 'MobFox-Android-SDK-master'. [incubating]
projects - Displays the sub-projects of root project 'MobFox-Android-SDK-master'.
properties - Displays the properties of root project 'MobFox-Android-SDK-master'.
tasks - Displays the tasks runnable from root project 'MobFox-Android-SDK-master'.

### Verification tasks

check - Runs all checks.
test - Runs the unit tests.

### Rules

Pattern: clean: Cleans the output files of a task.
Pattern: build: Assembles the artifacts of a configuration.
Pattern: upload: Assembles and uploads the artifacts belonging to a configuration.
To see all tasks and more detail, run gradle tasks --all
To see more detail about a task, run gradle help --task 
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 0s
1 actionable task: 1 executed

**1. What is the reason I cannot get all the task I got when I open a new project?

2. How can I add these tasks so I will be able to create apk file, build and execute integration tests?**

Answer (score 0):

`task`, you write in project level build.gradle file. See below pic for the reference.

[image]

*You are posting module level build.grale file.*

Comment: why am I not getting those implementations in the first place, if I use the 'java' plugin?

Comment: @BorisKatz, because in Android studio, it is generated when you create a new project. Gradle generates these all configuration.

Comment: I am not sure, I understand the reason. in my case I use java plug in, I imported the project to eclipse and android studio and still did not have those tasks.why did I not get it? and do you have links where can I find the code on the java plugin test and build implementations?

Answer (score 0):

Applying `com.android.application` should be enough, you should not apply `java plugin` on the root either and add dependencies there.

Operate on your app project, with Java specific stuff.

For more reference how to structure your project.
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/index.html

Comment: only if I remove the remarks from java plugin in the Build.gradle root file if am receiving the options I am looking for. Any idea why?

Comment: I'm confused, I don't understand your question.